# RealityKit – Set text programmatically of an Entity of Reality Composer

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

In my iOS app I want to introduce a part of AR using the new Reality Composer.

In my project I load a scene with this code:

```
let arView = ARView.init(frame: frame)

// Configure the AR session for horizontal plane tracking.

let arConfiguration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
arConfiguration.planeDetection = .horizontal
arView.session.run(arConfiguration)
arView.session.delegate = self

self.view.addSubview(arView)

Experience.loadSceneAsync{ [weak self] scene, error in

print("Error \(String(describing: error))")

guard let scene = scene else { return }

arView.scene.addAnchor(scene)

// THIS IS THE entity that i want to edit programmatically
scene.Label
```

The **"scene.label"** is a text object in my scene and I want to set text programmatically.

How can I do that?
It's possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

In RealityKit framework, use the following [type method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/meshresource) for generating 3D text:

```
static func generateText(_ string: String, 
                   extrusionDepth: Float, 
                             font: MeshResource.Font, 
                   containerFrame: CGRect, 
                        alignment: CTTextAlignment, 
                    lineBreakMode: CTLineBreakMode) -> MeshResource
```

Let's see how a real code looks like:

```
let textAnchor = try! SomeText.loadTextScene()

let textEntity: Entity = textAnchor.vacation!.children[0].children[0]

var textModelComponent = (textEntity.components[ModelComponent])!

textModelComponent.mesh = .generateText("Hello, World!",
                         extrusionDepth: 0.01,
                                   font: .systemFont(ofSize: 0.25),
                         containerFrame: CGRect.zero,
                              alignment: .center,
                          lineBreakMode: .byCharWrapping)

textAnchor.vacation!.children[0].children[0].components.set(textModelComponent)
arView.scene.anchors.append(textAnchor)
```