# Dynamically change text of RealityKit entity

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I have created a very simple scene ("SpeechScene") using Reality Composer, with a single speech callout object ("Speech Bubble") anchored to a `Face` anchor.

I have loaded this scene into code via the following:

```swift
let speechAnchor = try! Experience.loadSpeechScene()
arView.scene.anchors.append(speechAnchor)

let bubble = (arView.scene as? Experience.SpeechScene)?.speechBubble
```

It renders as expected. However, I would like to **dynamically** change the text of this existing entity.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647371/set-text-programmatically-of-an-entity-in-reality-composer-ios-13), but it's unclear to me how to refer to the `meshResource` property of a vanilla `RealityKit.Entity` object.

Is this possible? Thank you!

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 8):

### First Approach

[image]

> At first you need to find out what's an hierarchy in Reality Composer's scene containing `Bubble Speech` object. For that I used simple print() command:

```
print(textAnchor.swift!.children[0].components.self)   /* Bubble Plate */

print(textAnchor.swift!.children[1].components.self)   /* Text Object */
```

[image]

Now I can extract a text entity object:

```
let textEntity: Entity = textAnchor.swift!.children[1].children[0].children[0]
```

And bubble plate entity object:

```
let bubbleEntity: Entity = textAnchor.swift!.children[0]
```

> Here's a final code version that you can adapt for your needs:

```
import RealityKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let textAnchor = try! SomeText.loadTextScene()
        
        let textEntity: Entity = textAnchor.swift!.children[1].children[0].children[0]

        textAnchor.swift!.parent!.scale = [4,4,4]  // Scale for both objects
        
        var textModelComp: ModelComponent = (textEntity.components[ModelComponent])!
                
        var material = SimpleMaterial()
        material.baseColor = .color(.red)
        textModelComp.materials[0] = material

        textModelComp.mesh = .generateText("Obj-C",
                            extrusionDepth: 0.01,
                                      font: .systemFont(ofSize: 0.08),
                            containerFrame: CGRect(),
                                 alignment: .left,
                             lineBreakMode: .byCharWrapping)

        textEntity.position = [-0.1,-0.05, 0.01]

        textAnchor.swift!.children[1].children[0].children[0].components.set(textModelComp)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(textAnchor)
    }
}
```

[image]

### Second Approach

And you can always use a simpler approach for this case – to create several scenes in Reality Composer, each one must contain different `speech-object`.

[image]

> Consider, this code isn't for tracking, it's just a test for dynamically switching two objects using `Tap Gesture`. Then you need to adapt this code for tracking faces.

```
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    var counter = 0
    var bonjourObject: FaceExperience.Bonjour? = nil
    var holaObject: FaceExperience.Hola? = nil
     
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        // Reality Composer Scene named "Bonjour"
        // Model name – "french"
        bonjourObject = try! FaceExperience.loadBonjour()
        bonjourObject?.french?.scale = SIMD3(x: 2, y: 2, z: 2)
        bonjourObject?.french?.position.y = 0.25
        
        // Reality Composer Scene named "Hola"
        // Model name – "spanish"
        holaObject = try! FaceExperience.loadHola()
        holaObject?.spanish?.scale = SIMD3(x: 2, y: 2, z: 2)
        holaObject?.spanish?.position.z = 0.3
    }
    @IBAction func tapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {            
        if (counter % 2) == 0 {
            arView.scene.anchors.removeAll()
            arView.scene.anchors.append(holaObject!)
        } else {
            arView.scene.anchors.removeAll()
            arView.scene.anchors.append(bonjourObject!)
        }
        counter += 1
    }
}
```

[image]

If you want a text portion to be on the same place – just copy-paste object from one scene to another.

Comment: If I wanted to change text like this but then show it in a QLPreviewController rather than an ARView, how would I do that?

Comment: Thanks Andy.  Posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75126737/show-dynamically-changed-text-from-realtykit-entity-in-a-qlpreviewcontroller

Comment: Ok added some basic code.

Answer (score 5):

@maxxfrazer is correct in his assertion that currently the only way to change text dynamically is to replace the `ModelComponent`of the `Entity` assuming of course it adheres to the `HasModel Protocol`.

I have written a simple extension which can help with this:

```
//-------------------------
//MARK: - Entity Extensions
//-------------------------

extension Entity{

  /// Changes The Text Of An Entity
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - content: String
  func setText(_ content: String){ self.components[ModelComponent] = self.generatedModelComponent(text: content) }

  /// Generates A Model Component With The Specified Text
  /// - Parameter text: String
  func generatedModelComponent(text: String) -> ModelComponent{

    let modelComponent: ModelComponent = ModelComponent(

      mesh: .generateText(text, extrusionDepth: TextElements().extrusionDepth, font: TextElements().font,
                          containerFrame: .zero, alignment: .center, lineBreakMode: .byTruncatingTail),

      materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: TextElements().colour, isMetallic: true)]

    )

    return modelComponent
  }

}

//--------------------
//MARK:- Text Elements
//--------------------

/// The Base Setup Of The MeshResource
struct TextElements{

  let initialText = "Cube"
  let extrusionDepth: Float = 0.01
  let font: MeshResource.Font = MeshResource.Font.systemFont(ofSize: 0.05, weight: .bold)
  let colour: UIColor = .white

}
```

In order to use it lets say you create an `Entity` called `textEntity`:

```
 var textEntity = Entity()
```

You can then set the dynamically change the Text via replacing the `ModelComponent` and setting the `MeshResource` at any time by simply calling the following method:

```
textEntity.setText("Stack Overflow")
```

Of course in regard to centering or aligning the text you will need to do some simple calculations (which I have ommited here).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Find your model entity (maybe by putting a breakpoint and looking through the children initially), find the Entity that conforms to the HasModel protocol, then replace its model with a different one using generatetext:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/meshresource/3244422-generatetext