# File from Reality Composer not switching scenes on iPhone 7

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, realitykit, reality-composer

I've created multi-scene files in Reality Composer. They work fine within that software, but when I export them out to a `reality` file, load them onto my iPhone 7, and then run them, the interactive behaviors are working, but when I click on a button to change scenes, nothing happens.

Is this a known bug, or a feature not implemented yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug. Seemingly you do not append anchor holding B scene to an array of anchors, while removing previous anchor containing A scene.

You can read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58349044/dynamically-change-text-of-realitykit-entity/59127443#59127443) (a second approach) to find out how to implement a desired methodology.

```
@IBAction func tappedButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if (counter % 2) == 0 {
        arView.scene.anchors.removeAll()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(firstSceneAnchor!)
    } else {
        arView.scene.anchors.removeAll()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(secondSceneAnchor!)
    }
    counter += 1
}
```