# RealityKit – Load another Scene from the same Reality Composer project

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I create an Augmented Reality Project using Xcode's template.

Xcode creates a file called `Experience.rcproject`.

This project contains a scene called `Box` and a cube called `Steel Cube`.

I add 3 more scenes to  `Experience.rcproject`, called `alpha`, `bravo` and `delta`.

I run the project.

Xcode runs these two lines

```
// Load the "Box" scene from the "Experience" Reality File
let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBoxX(namedFile: "Ground")

// Add the box anchor to the scene
arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)
```

These lines load the Box scene from the Experience file.

Once this scene is loaded how do I switch to another scene `alpha`, `bravo` or `delta` without having to load the whole thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach in RealityKit to switch two or more scenes coming from Reality Composer is to use `removeAll()` instance method, allowing you to delete all the anchors from array.

You can switch two scenes using `asyncAfter(deadline:execute:)` method:

```
let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()
arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)

    
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
    
    self.arView.scene.anchors.removeAll()

    let sphereAnchor = try! Experience.loadSphere()
    self.arView.scene.anchors.append(sphereAnchor)
}
```

Or you can switch two different RC scenes using a regular `UIButton`:

```
@IBAction func loadNewSceneAndDeletePrevious(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.arView.scene.anchors.removeAll()

    let sphereAnchor = try! Experience.loadSphere()
    self.arView.scene.anchors.append(sphereAnchor)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This answer is amazing. I wish I could upvote you to the stratosphere! 

Comment: What about if I am using image recognition and I want the anchors to swap out when it recognises a new image? I have my scenes all setup in Reality Composer and have loaded the anchors so now I need to append each anchor as the image is recognised while using removeAll to remove the existing one.

Comment: Hi @JeremyRaven, yes it's possible. All you need to do is to remove an old model tethered with its image anchor from your scene (look at this `if-else condition` principle  – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61486389/file-from-reality-composer-not-switching-scenes-on-iphone-7/62264048#62264048) The idea is the same: `arView.scene.anchors.removeAll()`. In addition to the above, you may use anchor's id or reference image's name in `if condition`.

Comment: @AndyFedoroff Ill check the anchor id and reference image name. Many thanks :)

Comment: Is there a specific runtime function I can use to put the if statement into so it will always check when the image is changed?

Comment: I want to reload the same scene in it's default state to start Entities back where they started and restart the animations. When I try to removeAll() and append the scene again it crashes. Any ideas?