# How do I load my own Reality Composer scene into RealityKit?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I have created 3 "scenes" inside `Experience.rcproject` file, that is created when you start a new Augmented Reality project using xcode.

Working for 3D a lot, I would say that these were 3 objects inside a scene, but inside `Experience.rcproject` I have added 3 "scenes". Inside each one, the same 3D model. The first one is attached to an horizontal plane, the second one to a vertical plane and the third one to an image.

I am woking with Reality Kit for the first time and learning along the way.

My idea of doing so, is to load the right object when I want to have it attached to the horizontal, vertical or image.

This is how I accomplished this.

I have modified `Experience.swift` file provided by Apple to accept scene names, like this:

```
public static func loadBox(namedFile:String) throws -> Experience.Box {
    guard let realityFileURL = Foundation.Bundle(for: Experience.Box.self).url(forResource: "Experience", withExtension: "reality") else {
      throw Experience.LoadRealityFileError.fileNotFound("Experience.reality")
    }
    
    let realityFileSceneURL = realityFileURL.appendingPathComponent(namedFile, isDirectory: false)
    let anchorEntity = try Experience.Box.loadAnchor(contentsOf: realityFileSceneURL)
    return createBox(from: anchorEntity)
  }
```

and I call this line

```
let entity = try! Experience.loadBox(namedFile:sceneName)
```

whatever I want, but I have to use this code:

```
// I have to keep a reference to the entity so I can remove it from its parent and nil
currentEntity?.removeFromParent()
currentEntity = nil

// I have to load the entity again, now with another name
let entity = try! Experience.loadBox(namedFile:sceneName)

// store a reference to it, so I can remove it in the future
currentEntity = entity

// remove the old one from the scene
arView.scene.anchors.removeAll()

// add the new one
arView.scene.anchors.append(entity)
```

This code is stupid and I am sure there is a better way.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Hierarchy in RealityKit / Reality Composer

I think it's rather a "theoretical" question than practical. At first I should say that editing `Experience` file containing scenes with anchors and entities isn't good idea.

In RealityKit and Reality Composer there's quite definite hierarchy in case you created single object in default scene:

```
Scene –> AnchorEntity -> ModelEntity 
                              |
                           Physics
                              |
                          Animation
                              |
                            Audio
```

If you placed two 3D models in a scene they share the same anchor:

```
Scene –> AnchorEntity – – – -> – – – – – – – – ->
                             |                  |
                       ModelEntity01      ModelEntity02
                             |                  |
                          Physics            Physics
                             |                  |
                         Animation          Animation
                             |                  |
                           Audio              Audio
```

`AnchorEntity` in RealityKit defines what properties of `World Tracking` config are running in current `ARSession`: `horizontal`/`vertical` plane detection and/or `image detection`, and/or `body detection`, etc.

Let's look at those parameters:

```
AnchorEntity(.plane(.horizontal, classification: .floor, minimumBounds: [1, 1]))

AnchorEntity(.plane(.vertical, classification: .wall, minimumBounds: [0.5, 0.5]))

AnchorEntity(.image(group: "Group", name: "model"))
```

Here you can read about [Entity-Component-System](https://medium.com/macoclock/realitykit-911-entity-component-system-ecs-bfe0520e0e8e) paradigm.

### Combining two scenes coming from Reality Composer

For this post I've prepared two scenes in Reality Composer – first scene (`ConeAndBox`) with a horizontal plane detection and a second scene (`Sphere`) with a vertical plane detection. If you combine these scenes in RealityKit into one bigger scene, you'll get two types of plane detection – horizontal and vertical.

[image]

Two cone and box are pinned to one anchor in this scene.

[image]

In RealityKit I can combine these scenes into one scene.

```
// Plane Detection with a Horizontal anchor
let coneAndBoxAnchor = try! Experience.loadConeAndBox()
coneAndBoxAnchor.children[0].anchor?.scale = [7, 7, 7]
coneAndBoxAnchor.goldenCone!.position.y = -0.1  //.children[0].children[0].children[0]
arView.scene.anchors.append(coneAndBoxAnchor)

coneAndBoxAnchor.name = "mySCENE"
coneAndBoxAnchor.children[0].name = "myANCHOR"
coneAndBoxAnchor.children[0].children[0].name = "myENTITIES"

print(coneAndBoxAnchor)
     
// Plane Detection with a Vertical anchor
let sphereAnchor = try! Experience.loadSphere()
sphereAnchor.steelSphere!.scale = [7, 7, 7]
arView.scene.anchors.append(sphereAnchor)

print(sphereAnchor)
```

[image]

In Xcode's console you can see `ConeAndBox` scene hierarchy with names given in RealityKit:

[image]

And you can see `Sphere` scene hierarchy with no names given:

[image]

And it's important to note that our combined scene now contains two scenes in an array. Use the following command to print this array:

```
print(arView.scene.anchors)
```

It prints:

```
[ 'mySCENE' : ConeAndBox, '' : Sphere ]
```

You can reassign a type of tracking via `AnchoringComponent` (instead of plane detection you can assign an image detection):

```
coneAndBoxAnchor.children[0].anchor!.anchoring = AnchoringComponent(.image(group: "AR Resources", 
                                                                            name: "planets"))
```

### Retrieving entities and connecting them to new AnchorEntity

For decomposing/reassembling an hierarchical structure of your scene, you need to retrieve all entities and pin them to a single anchor. Take into consideration – tracking one anchor is less intensive task than tracking several ones. And one anchor is much more stable – in terms of the relative positions of scene models – than, for instance, 20 anchors.

```
let coneEntity = coneAndBoxAnchor.goldenCone!
coneEntity.position.x = -0.2
    
let boxEntity = coneAndBoxAnchor.plasticBox!
boxEntity.position.x = 0.01
    
let sphereEntity = sphereAnchor.steelSphere!
sphereEntity.position.x = 0.2
    
let anchor = AnchorEntity(.image(group: "AR Resources", name: "planets")
anchor.addChild(coneEntity)
anchor.addChild(boxEntity)
anchor.addChild(sphereEntity)
    
arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
```

### Useful links

Now you have a deeper understanding of how to construct scenes and retrieve entities from those scenes. If you need other examples look at [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58349044/dynamically-change-text-of-realitykit-entity/59127443#59127443) and [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62533302/realitykit-load-another-scene-from-the-same-reality-composer-project/62534226#62534226).

### P.S.

Additional code showing how to upload scenes from `ExperienceX.rcproject`:

```
import ARKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                    
        // RC generated "loadGround()" method automatically
        let groundArrowAnchor = try! ExperienceX.loadGround()
        groundArrowAnchor.arrowFloor!.scale = [2,2,2]
        arView.scene.anchors.append(groundArrowAnchor)

        print(groundArrowAnchor)
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You answer is fantastic. Thanks. Just one question: I see that you have two separate methods, `loadConeAndBox()` and `loadSphere()`. Will those be copies of the original Apple's `loadBox()`? Excuse my stupidity but can you please post this part of your code?

Comment: Yes, I modified a default Reality Composer's "Box" scene, putting there just Cone model.

Comment: I ask this because I thought the scene names would be exposed in code in a way that could be used in the loading methods. Anyway, see my `loadBox:namedFile` above. I guess you mean that.

Comment: Thanks again. Now I have to discover why calls to this `loadBox()` are leaking in my code. But this is [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62823901/leak-in-call-to-code-created-by-apple-but-where) .

Comment: @Duck, just one thing – as I've written in this post, editing `Experience` file is not a good idea... Maybe memory leak is a result of this...

Comment: so how do I load one scene or the other?

Comment: Please give me your real Reality Composer project.

Comment: [here we go](https://easyupload.io/6mqoqr)... please explain how do I load Ground and Wall and have access to ArrowGround and ArrowWall like you explained in your code without modifying Apple's original `loadBox()`?

Comment: this is what I am talking about... `loadGound()` does not exist in my code. Can you show the code you would put on your `loadGround()` to see if we are talking the same thing? thanks.

Comment: one of my problems is that I was using a copy of `Experience.swift` and that copy was not being updated, obviously, with the scene names. Now, it is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @AndyFedoroff, I was reading your post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623726/what-is-the-real-focal-length-of-the-camera-used-in-realitykit/62627471#62627471. I am wondering does that mean ARKit always used focal length of 28mm (including face tracking) regardless we see it as 20mm printed in the iPhone X?

Comment: Hi @swiftlearneer, For rear camera – yes, it uses 28mm. For selfie camera – don't know, there's no any info.

Comment: @AndyFedoroff Thanks! I see! So the intrinsic matrix here only refers to the rear (back) camera and not the TruthDepth camera? Would I have to go look into AVCameraCalibrationData instead?

Comment: I'll look into it tomorrow. I'm interested in it too))

Comment: @AndyFedoroff Thanks and that would be great!

Comment: @AndyFedoroff. If I can ask a follow up question for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623726/what-is-the-real-focal-length-of-the-camera-used-in-realitykit/62627471#62627471 . I tried "@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!" "sceneView.pointOfView?.camera?.focalLength" but got an error "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';' "

Comment: @AndyFedoroff. It works now when I put inside a function and call it. However, this intrinsic parameters are always the same for the back camera even though I move it along?

Comment: To make parameters to be updated use `renderer(...)` or `session(...)` delegate methods. They work when ARSCNViewDelegate or ARSessionDelegate is implemented. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview/2865797-delegate and. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/2865614-delegate

Comment: Hi @AndyFedoroff! Did not check you comment but I will give this a try for the back camera! Do you have any luck with the True Depth camera parameters? I followed this suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62927167/swift-get-the-truthdepth-camera-parameters-for-face-tracking-in-arkit it seems that it would work for capturing photo rather than working with face tracking (capturing frame)

Comment: So I put your suggestions as a function https://imgur.com/Ps9uxlg like so; how should I merge with renderer here: https://imgur.com/8tw7WVV; ? The renderer I have is for the nodes updates. I am sorry for posting screenshot; I wish I could have a better way to contact you:(

Comment: Hi @swiftlearneer, Sorry I'm on vacation till 30th August. I have only smartphone with me, so it's a little bit inconvenient to answer posts from smartphone((. And internet speed isn't always good. Have a good time, see you later!

Comment: All good! @AndyFedoroff! Just a quick question you have this in mind, as it was for your earlier post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57582930/why-does-arfaceanchor-have-negative-z-position. If you know how to flip the z axis for ARFaceAnchor? I tried to figure out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63023016/swift-correct-the-arfaceanchor-from-left-handed-to-right-handed-coordinate-syst. Have a nice vacation:)

Comment: Hey @Duck! Could you ask you a question about `function render` in Scenekit/ARkit related question? :(

Comment: @swiftlearneer - I am still learning reality kit... never used that function.

Comment: @Duck All good! Btw following some of your posts and they are good!

Comment: @swiftlearneer - Thanks. I have to ask everything, because the documentation apple writes is written with disdain.

Comment: Hi @Duck! Quick question. Do you know how to capture scene view audio and video output of the user? I think I saw one of your posts earlier about this but not too sure if I can find it now. Currently I am using Replay kit to achieve these but has some delay in between because of the user permission... Could you please help :(