# RealityKit – Get a model entity from USDZ file

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, realitykit, usdz, reality-composer

I haave a file (exists in main bundle with target membership checked) named `matrix.usdz` and need to load it with

```
 do {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Matrix", ofType: "usdz")!
  
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        
    let assetsLoader = try Entity.load(contentsOf: url)
  }
  catch {
     print(error)
  }
```

But it crashes with

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

on this line

```
let assetsLoader = try Entity.load(contentsOf: url)
```

Preview

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an [anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893075/what-is-aranchor-exactly/52899502#52899502) if you need to load an entity into your scene. In order to get a ModelEntity, you need to grab it from the scene [hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62825198/how-do-i-load-my-own-reality-composer-scene-into-realitykit/62828777#62828777) using `.children[X]` subscript.

```
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()            
        do {
            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Matrix", ofType: "usdz")!
         
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
               
            // Scene
            let scene = try Entity.load(contentsOf: url)          
            print(scene)
            
            // Entity
            let entity = scene.children[0].........children[0] as! ModelEntity
            
            entity.model?.materials[0] = UnlitMaterial(color: .red)
            
            let anchor = AnchorEntity(plane: .any)
            anchor.addChild(scene)
            arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)

         } catch {
             print(error)
         }
    }
}
```

You can also get a model this way:

```
let modelEntity = try Entity.loadModel(contentsOf: url)
                    
modelEntity.model?.materials[0] = UnlitMaterial(color: .red)
```

### P.S.

I should say that you have an obvious naming error – "Matrix" vs "matrix". Also `Matrix.rcproject` and `Matrix.usdz` are not the same. To load `Matrix.rcproject` (Reality Composer project) use the following approach:

[image]

```
// .rcproject
let scene = try! Matrix.loadCircle()

let circleEntity = scene.children[0]...........children[0] as! ModelEntity
```

to load a USDZ model use this one:

```
// .usdz
let model = try! Entity.loadModel(named: "Matrix", in: nil)
```

But as far as I know, you do not need an RC project, so export USDZ from Reality Composer.

[image]

To load `.reality` file use the following approach:

```
// .reality
let carModel = try! Entity.loadAnchor(named: "car")
print(carModel)

arView.scene.addAnchor(carModel)
```

### Here's your USDZ model on iOS simulator:

[image]

Comment: Will vote for now until it worked fully with me

Comment: can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71046033/cant-load-a-realitykit-model