# Show dynamically changed text from RealtyKit entity in a QLPreviewController

Tags: swift, realitykit, arquicklook

There is a good [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58349044/dynamically-change-text-of-realitykit-entity/59127443?noredirect=1#comment132575989_59127443) and answer here about dynamically changing text of an entity in a Reality Composer scene.  Is there a way to do the same but show it in a QLPreviewController rather than an ARView?

Here is code for loading a previewItem (from a URL) into the QLPreviewController.  So I would like to dynamically change the text in the file before returning the preview item to display.  Assume I am using a .rcproject that has a bubble text, for example.

```
class ARQLViewController: UIViewController, 
                          QLPreviewControllerDataSource, 
                          QLPreviewControllerDelegate {

    var allowsContentScaling = true
    var webViewModel: WebViewModel

    init(webViewModelReceived: WebViewModel) {
        webViewModel = webViewModelReceived
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        setupOnAppear()
    }

    func setupOnAppear() {
        let previewController = QLPreviewController()
        previewController.dataSource = self
        previewController.delegate = self
        present(previewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, 
                    previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
        let url = webViewModel.afUrlForAR  
        let previewItem = ARQuickLookPreviewItem(fileAt: url!)
        previewItem.allowsContentScaling = allowsContentScaling
        return previewItem
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### About QLPreviewController

`AR QuickLook` is based on the RealityKit engine and it serves to preview AR QuickLook items in `.usdz` or `.reality` format with lighting (including soft contact shadows and PBR materials), light estimation, animation, gestures, anchoring, sound and file sharing. It was conceived as a zero-config view controller for AR scenes.

Since the model is `QLPreviewItem` or `ARQuickLookPreviewItem`, you will not be able to change model's parameters or its hierarchy. ***So the answer is: you can preview `.usdz` and `.reality` models with animation and physics in QLPreviewController but you cannot change their parameters, the way you used to do in RealityKit.***

The code for creating an ARQuickLook app is short and concise:

```
import QuickLook

class ViewController: UIViewController, QLPreviewControllerDataSource {

    func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int { 1 }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let arController = QLPreviewController()
        arController.dataSource = self
        present(arController, animated: true)
    }

    func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController,
                    previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
        
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ar3", ofType: "usdz")!
        return URL(fileURLWithPath: path) as QLPreviewItem
    }
}
```